# Pagination with express-paginate module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pagination

I am trying to use the [mongoose-paginate](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate) and [express-paginate](https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate#example) as advised on both GitHub repositories. I have set up the mongoose-paginate in my model and have the correct response, but can't seem to figure out how to use the express-paginate within my routes and view. I have 11 or 12 entries in my database and it picks up correctly to create a second page, but it isn't finding paginate in my view file.

Right response from model setup:

```
Pages: 2
[ { content: 'maybe not',
    author: 'Connor John',
    title: 'This is the 11 test',
    _id: 540487ddc787d60000000009,
    __v: 0,
    date: Thu Sep 04 2014 19:48:02 GMT-0400 (EDT) } ]
```

blogModel.js (using mongoose-paginate):

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;



var BlogPostSchema  = new Schema({
        title: String,
        author: String,
        content: String,
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

BlogPostSchema.plugin( mongoosePaginate );

var Blogpost = mongoose.model("Blogpost", BlogPostSchema);

Blogpost.paginate({}, 2, 10, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, count) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Pages:', pageCount);
        console.log(blogpost);
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blogpost', BlogPostSchema);
```

routes.js (express-paginate):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');
var paginate = require('express-paginate');

//index
    router.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res) {
    var drinks = [
            {   name: 'Bloody Mary', drunkness: 3 },
            {   name: 'Martini', drunkness: 5 },
            {   name: 'Scotch', drunkness: 10}
        ];

        var tagline = "Lets do this.";

        res.render('pages/index', {
            drinks: drinks,
            tagline: tagline
        });
    });


app.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));


//blog
    router.route('/blog') 

        // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // set the date of the post
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json({ message: 'Blog created.' });
                });

        }) // END POST method


        // START GET method
        .get(function(req, res, next) {

            Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {

                if (err) return next(err)

            Blogpost.find(function(err, blogpost) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                blogpost.title = req.body.title; // update the blog title
                blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
                blogpost.content = req.body.content; // update the blog content
                blogpost.date = req.body.date; // set the date of the post

                res.format({
                    html: function() {
                        res.render('pages/blog', {
                            blogpost: blogpost,
                            pageCount: pageCount,
                            itemCount: itemCount
                        })
                    },
                    json: function() {

                        res.json({
                            object: 'blogpost',
                            has_more: paginate.hasNextPages(req)(pageCount),
                            data: blogpost
                        })
                    }
                });
            }) //END Find Blogpost 
        }); // END GET method


    //Route for individual blogs
    router.route('/blog/:blogpost_id')

    // START GET method blog by ID  
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blog) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(blog);
        });
    }) // END GET method blog by ID

    // START PUT method
    .put(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blogpost) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);


            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // update the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // update the blog content
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // set the date of the post

            blogpost.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);


                res.json({ message: 'Blog updated.' });
            });

        });

    }) // END PUT method

    // START DELETE method
    .delete(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.remove({
            _id: req.params.blogpost_id

        }, function(err, bear) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        });
    });


}); //END Paginate

//about
    router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/about');
    });


module.exports = router;
```

paginate.ejs (express-paginate):

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1-1">
        <div class="paginate">


                <ul>
                <% if (paginate.hasPreiousPages) { %>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<%=paginate.href().prev %>">Previous</a>
                    </li>
                <% } %>

                <% if (paginate.hasNextPages) { %>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<%=paginate.href().next %>">Next</a>
                    </li>
                <% } %>
                </ul>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

blog.ejs (express-paginate):

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <div class="body-content">
                <% blogpost.forEach(function(blogpost) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h2><%= blogpost.title %></h2></td>
                        <td><h3><%= blogpost.author %></h3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="paginate">
        <% include ../partials/paginate %>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

error message:

```
ReferenceError: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/views/pages/blog.ejs:7
    5| 
    6| <body>
 >> 7| 
    8|  <header>
    9|      <% include ../partials/header %>
    10|     </header>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.paginate()` in your model definition? That is not meant to be there, as you only "call" in your actual code to get the results.

Comment: @NeilLunn it was to test that the module was being loaded correctly. With `.paginate()` removed from the `blogModel.js` file, I am still getting issues relating to how I'm trying to use the paginate object witihn my `paginate.ejs` file.

Comment: can you remove the paginate from the model example please, and adjust it removing anything unecessary, and from what you have learned?  its throwing me off a bit too, so causing me to not like the question much because not seeming to want to do things the right way.Im having some similar paginate issues and was hoping to build on this topic.  If you solved, can you please add your solution in the answer?  Your title makes it hard to understand what you need, can you adjust possibly?